# How can i use testcontainer in mac os with out Docker Desktop?

Tags: spring, docker, docker-desktop, testcontainers

Today, I heard news that the docker desktop will be not free. So, our team has conclusion to delete Docker Desktop and use minikube.

Then, we can use docker cli, but, when we use testContainer in Java project(We use intellij) the testContainer not work because of Docker. how can we solve this problem?

```
Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.2, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.2, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1326)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:643)
    at org.testcontainers.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchContainer.<init>(ElasticsearchContainer.java:73)
    at org.testcontainers.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchContainer.<init>(ElasticsearchContainer.java:57)
    at com.wmp.ep.index.manager.service.IndexManageServiceTest.beforeClass(IndexManageServiceTest.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:384)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1508)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$4(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:156)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:148)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:146)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:188)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:101)
    at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.listImagesCmd(DockerClientDelegate.java:167)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
    at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:18)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:67)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:28)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:39)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1324)
    ... 84 more
```

Comment: AFAIK testcontainers is pretty much tied in to Docker (at least currently) and using something else isn't (yet) supported. I also believe that not paying will actually be more expensive than you (or rather your whole team/organization) trying to figure out how to run this without docker. A bit of ["penny wise but pound foolish"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penny-wise%20and%2Fbut%20pound-foolish#:~:text=%3A%20careful%20about%20small%20amounts%20of,%2Dwise%20and%20pound%2Dfoolish.)

Comment: You can also wait until AtomicJar provides public access to [Testcontainers Cloud](https://www.atomicjar.com/2021/11/announcing-testcontainers-cloud/). No need for a local Docker installation anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We looked at various ways to run Testcontainers based tests in Windows and Macos: https://www.atomicjar.com/2021/10/docker-on-windows-and-macos/

This experiment was done based on the testcontainers-java test suite itself, so it covers all the features of the library well. For example, Minikube exposes Docker and showed reasonable results. One thing to note is how you can expose your filesystem to the containers which requires mounting them first into the minikube.
So I'd recommend using `copyTo/FromContainer` methods instead of mounting things.

To configure minikube to be used from Testcontainers use the `testcontainers.properties` file, like (example from the article linked above):

```
$ eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
$ echo "docker.host=$DOCKER_HOST" >> ~/.testcontainers.properties
$ echo "docker.cert.path=$DOCKER_CERT_PATH" >> ~/.testcontainers.properties
$ echo "docker.tls.verify=true" >> ~/.testcontainers.properties
```

Alternatively you can use [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io/) which exposes Docker, or remote Docker environments, for example [Testcontainers Cloud](https://testcontainers.cloud). In case of Testcontainers cloud your tests run locally, but the containers in the cloud, so there's no issues with architecture or OS incompatibilities.